# How to integrate CCAVENUE manually

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

how to integrate ccavenue manually in magento 1.9.

i followed those steps but did't get any option in payment method

- Step1: Get module from CCAVENUE
- Step2: Get your working key from CCAVENUE site. Keep your merchant id handy.
- Step3: Open the module folder. Copy the folder Avenues to `app\code\core\Mage`
- Step4: From Module folder Copy the file Mage_Avenues .xml to `app\etc\modules`
- Step5: From module folder Copy the folder avenues to `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template`
- Step6: Open `..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\StandardController.php` and mention your working key in it.
- Step7: Open `..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\libfuncs.php` goto line 56. function cdec, and add `$dec = 0`; within it before the loop. (this solves the variable not defined bug)
- Step8: In Magento backend Refresh all cache and reindex all
- Step9: In CCAVENUE backend setup redirect page.
- Step10: SETTING IT UP IN MAGENTO: • Click on configuration, Click on payment methods, Select Cavenuepayment, Enter the merchant_Id, Enter the workingkey Save configuration

---

i followed those steps but did't get any option in payment method
 Step1: Get module from CCAVENUE

Step2: Get your working key from CCAVENUE site. Keep your merchant id handy.

Step3: Open the module folder. Copy the folder Avenues to magento\app\code\core\Mage

Step4: From Module folder Copy the file Mage_Avenues .xml to magento\app\etc\modules

Step5: From module folder Copy the folder avenues to magento app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template

Step6: Open ..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\StandardController.php and mention your working key in it.

Step7: Open ..\app\code\core\Mage\avenues\controllers\libfuncs.php goto line 56. function cdec, and add $dec = 0; within it before the loop. (this solves the variable not defined bug)

Step8: In Magento backend Refresh all cache and reindex all
Step9: In CCAVENUE backend setup redirect page.
Step10: SETTING IT UP IN MAGENTO: • Click on configuration, Click on payment methods, Select Cavenuepayment, Enter the merchant_Id, Enter the workingkey Save configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to get CCavenue payment extension from official team and than install the extension by copying the files to root of site....

Comment: i am new in magento so i don't know how to integrate CCavenue payment gateway in my website plz suggest me an easy way for it?

Comment: @user55879 This is an easy and only way..... contact them [here](https://dashboard.ccavenue.com/web/contactUs.do?command=navigateContactUs) and ask for magento extension , they will send you files and you need to copy those files to root of the site and than you need to do configuration in `system > configuration > Payement methods` , thats all.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento : may i know if you know about ccavenue payment page not redirct,, shall i ask more?

Comment: @Rathinam i didt integrated ccavenue payment gateway, so contacting extension team is better.......